# Extend Options list in Kibana to show only special values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have created a dashboard in Kibana ElasticSearch.
In the dashboard, I have added a filter that will only show me certain devices with serial number XY. This also works perfectly so far.

For example, the filter looks like this:

`sn.number is one of 00001, 00002, 00003`.

Now I have a filter selection which filters by country, model, name etc..

Additionally there is a section: Serial number

But when I open the dropdown bar it shows me all serial numbers, i.e.

```
> 00001
> 00002
> 00003
> 00004
> 00005
```

I only want to reduce the selection to my 3 devices (**00001**, **00002**, **00003**).

When I want to edit the visualization, I cannot find a way to do this.

[image: Options list in Kibana]

Can someone help me further or give some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy Controls do not support pre-filtering filter values.

The workarounds are:

1. Create a parent filter that will filter serial numbers to the ones you need.
2. Create a filtered alias that contains those serial numbers:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

```
POST _aliases
{
   "actions":[
      {
         "add":{
            "index":"original-index",
            "alias":"filtered-for-controller-index",
            "filter":{
               "term":{
                  "some_field":"some_value"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

There is a new project around controls and this feature is in the Roadmap:

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/140112